# Selecionar imagem da galeria e enviar por post?

Tags: angularjs, apache-cordova, ionic

Estou criando um cadastro de novos usuarios e nesse cadastro o usuario deve escolher sua imagem de perfil(obrigatorio). Eu consigo retornar a imagem da galeria mas o nome da imagem nao retorna, o retorno eh esse: `localURL: "content://media/external/images/media/8018"`. Eu quero o nome da imagem para poder enviar para meu webservice por post.

Como eu faço isso ?

estou tentando assim.

**template**

```
<ion-view view-title="Cadastro" align-title="center">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
      <button class="button button-clear ion-arrow-left-c" ng-click="goBack();">        
      </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>    

    <ion-content>

    <form name="User">

      <div>          
          <img ng-src="img/ionic.png" id="smallimage" width="150" heigth="150">
          <input type="file" ng-model="User.imageFile" size="30" id="imageFile" required="true"/>
          <button class="button button-stable"  ng-click="selectImage();">Imagem</button>
      </div>

       <div class="list list-inset">
              <label class="item item-input">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Nome" ng-model="User.nome" required="true">
              </label>
              <br/>
              <label class="item item-input">
                  <input type="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="User.email" required="true">
              </label>
              <br/>
              <label class="item item-input">
                  <input type="password" placeholder="Senha" ng-model="User.senha" ng-minlength="8" maxlength="8"
                   required="true">
              </label>
              <br/>                         
        </div>

    </form>
    <button type="button" class="button button-block button-energized"  
                ng-disabled="User.$invalid" ng-click="addUsuarioApp(User);">Cadastrar</button>

    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**factory camera**

```
var app = angular.module('starter');

app.factory('CameraFactory', ['$q', function($q) {

    var options = {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: 0,      // 0:Photo Library, 1=Camera, 2=Saved Photo Album        
    }    

    var onSuccess = function(imageData) { 
         window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageData, function(fileEntry) {
                fileEntry.file(function(filee) {
                    console.log(filee);
                    //exibe: localURL: "content://media/external/images/media/8018"
                });
            });         
        var image = document.getElementById('smallimage');  
        var imageFile = document.getElementById('imageFile');    
        image.src = imageData; 
        imageFile.value = imageData;    
    };

    var onFail = function(e) {
        console.log("onFail! " + e);        
    };

    return {
        getPicture: function() {
            return navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess,onFail,options);
    }
  }
}]);
```

**User controller**

```
var app = angular.module("starter");

app.controller("UserCtrl", function($scope, CameraFactory){

$scope.selectImage = function() {
        CameraFactory.getPicture();
    };    
}
```